# Rank Last Values in Arrays and Loop Ranked Number into Previously Created Array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, ranking

I need to take the last value of each array in a multidimensional array, compare them to each other, and put the ranked value at the end of the previously created arrays.

My PHP:

```
//Arrays
$rsIdeas_array = array();
$total_rank_array = array();

//Get Data
//MySQL Select Queries Here
//loop bizideas into array
do {
//Calculate variables needed
$search_rank = round(($row_rsIdeas['monthlysearches'] / $row_rsMaxSearches['monthlysearches'] * 9) + 1, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
$competition_rank = round(10 - (($row_rsIdeas['advcomp'] / ($row_rsMaxCompetition['advcomp']) * 9)), 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
$search_competition_ease = ($search_rank + $competition_rank + $row_rsIdeas['startease']);
$row_rsIdeas['search_rank'] = $search_rank;
$row_rsIdeas['competition_rank'] = $competition_rank;
$row_rsIdeas['search_competition_ease'] = $search_competition_ease;

$row_rsIdeas = array(
  'ideaID' => $row_rsIdeas['ideaID'],
  'userID' => $row_rsIdeas['userID'],
  'bizidea' => $row_rsIdeas['bizidea'],
  'bizexplained' => $row_rsIdeas['bizexplained'],
  'bizmodel' => $row_rsIdeas['bizmodel'],
  'repkeyword' => $row_rsIdeas['repkeyword'],
  'monthlysearches' => $row_rsIdeas['monthlysearches'],
  'search_rank' => $row_rsIdeas['search_rank'],
  'advcomp' => $row_rsIdeas['advcomp'],
  'competition_rank' => $row_rsIdeas['competition_rank'],
  'search_competition_ease' => $row_rsIdeas['search_competition_ease'],
);
array_push($rsIdeas_array, $row_rsIdeas);
array_push($total_rank_array, $search_competition_ease);
} while ($row_rsIdeas = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsIdeas));
```

This Produces

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ideaID] => 1
        [userID] => 1
        [bizidea] => Business Idea 1
        [bizexplained] => Business Idea 1 Explanation
        [bizmodel] => Utility
        [repkeyword] => Business Idea 1 Keyword
        [monthlysearches] => 33100
        [search_rank] => 1
        [advcomp] => 0.95
        [competition_rank] => 1.1
        [search_competition_ease] => 8.1 //Value to Rank From
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ideaID] => 2
        [userID] => 1
        [bizidea] => Business Idea 2
        [bizexplained] => Business Idea 2 Explained
        [bizmodel] => Service
        [repkeyword] => Business 2 Keyword
        [monthlysearches] => 6600
        [search_rank] => 1
        [advcomp] => 0.93
        [competition_rank] => 1.3
        [search_competition_ease] => 10.3 //Value to Rank From
    )
)
```

I have a section that produces a ranking:

```
arsort($total_rank_array); 
$rank = 1;
foreach($total_rank_array as $ideaId => $value) {
print('Rank: ' . $rank . '<br />Value: ' . $value . '<br />');
$rank++;
```

Which Creates (the higher the number, the better the rank):

```
Rank: 1
Value: 10.3
Rank: 2
Value: 8.1
```

I need to put these values at the end of the correct arrays without rearranging the order of the arrays. Here is an example of what I would like in the completed array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ideaID] => 1
        [userID] => 1
        [bizidea] => Business Idea 1
        [bizexplained] => Business Idea 1 Explanation
        [bizmodel] => Utility
        [repkeyword] => Business Idea 1 Keyword
        [monthlysearches] => 33100
        [search_rank] => 1
        [advcomp] => 0.95
        [competition_rank] => 1.1
        [search_competition_ease] => 8.1
        [total_rank] => 2 //Here is where I need the additional value
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ideaID] => 2
        [userID] => 1
        [bizidea] => Business Idea 2
        [bizexplained] => Business Idea 2 Explained
        [bizmodel] => Service
        [repkeyword] => Business 2 Keyword
        [monthlysearches] => 6600
        [search_rank] => 1
        [advcomp] => 0.93
        [competition_rank] => 1.3
        [search_competition_ease] => 10.3
        [total_rank] => 1 //Here is where I need the additional value
    )
)
```

How can I accomplish this? I apologize for including so much code, I just want to make sure I am completely understood.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code, this should work:

```
arsort($total_rank_array);
foreach (array_keys($total_rank_array) as $i => $key)
{
    $rsIdeas_array[$key]['total_rank'] = $i+1;
}
```